# R - Reverse order with cut

Tags: r, reverse, cut

I want to split a vector according to given cutoffs (or breaks) into bins in R.

This can be done as followed:

```
numbers <- 1:10
cutoffs <- c(0,2,6,7,10, Inf)

data.frame(data = numbers, bins = as.integer(cut(numbers, breaks = cutoffs, right = FALSE)))
```

This will result in the following:

```
   data bins
1     1    1
2     2    2
3     3    2
4     4    2
5     5    2
6     6    3
7     7    4
8     8    4
9     9    4
10   10    5
```

However, what I want is for **the lowest value to be in the highest bin** and vice versa. So somehow I want to achieve the following instead:

```
   data bins
1     1    5
2     2    4
3     3    4
4     4    4
5     5    4
6     6    3
7     7    2
8     8    2
9     9    2
10   10    1
```

I have tried many combinations with 'rev()' to reverse the sequence. But keep in mind I cannot just reverse the results of the earlier cut-command as they are asymmetrical.

I realise there might be a simple solution to this, but for some reason it keeps escaping me. Any suggestions in which direction I should look?

Comment: Couldn't you subtract the original `bins` from 6?

Comment: you could use the `labels` argument .. `as.integer(as.character(cut(numbers, breaks = cutoffs, labels=5:1, right = FALSE)))`

Comment: @d.b that.. does the trick.. Thanks for that! I was too focused on using the cut alone for this that I overlooked something as simple as that.

Comment: @user20650 thanks for your comment too, your idea also works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you wanted the left interval boundaries closed and wanted an integer result then `findInterval` (rather than `cut`) is the natural choice:

```
data.frame(data = numbers, bins = 6L - findInterval(numbers, vec = cutoffs)) 
   data bins
1     1    5
2     2    4
3     3    4
4     4    4
5     5    4
6     6    3
7     7    2
8     8    2
9     9    2
10   10    1
>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer also does the trick. Exactly what I needed!

Comment: And if you wanted to make it programmatic you might substitute max() expression for the '6L'.

Answer (score 5):

Change the arguments to the cut() function by negating the dataframes and setting the value of right=TRUE, so that the interval becomes (-inf,0].

The desired result is achieved.

```
data.frame(data = numbers, bins = as.integer(cut(-numbers, breaks = -cutoffs, right = TRUE)))
```

Comment: A good answer too, thanks for this. I accepted the other one because it's a bit easier to read for me (as we are using double negation here).